# useReducer of React is async

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reducers

I have this piece of code:

```
const [hDate, dispatch] = useReducer(hDateReducer, initialHDate)

const onChange= (field) => {
        dispatch({ type: field.id, value: Number.parseInt(field.value) })
        const h_date_str = hDate.year+'/'+hDate.month+'/'+hDate.day
        setTimeout(function(){ props.onChange(h_date_str) }, 3000);
 }
```

The value passed to the parent is always a step behind my current dispatching. Even though I added a timeout I still get the same result. Is there any way to deal with the synchronicity of `setReducer` (also `setState`)?

Comment: You've already captured the value, delaying the call to props.onChange won't help. That said, I don't know the answer.. `this.setState` had a callback we could use but they took that away from us.

Comment: Why doesn't the parent use the value from the state container? It seems weird to have two ways of passing it around (via the state container *and* via a callback).

Comment: Yes I already get the value but when I pass it back to the parent I get the old one!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am using hooks with no redux neither container pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

1. updated value will be provided in next render run
2. your function is bound to `hDate` by closure. Regardless of `setTimeout` usage your code will always use value from moment your function is declared.

in this particular case you probably may utilize `useEffect` to run callback prop

```
useEffect(() => {
 props.onChange(hDate);
}, [props.onChange, hDate]
);
```

[upd]
previously it was

```
useEffect(() =>
 props.onChange(hDate), 
  [props.onChange, hDate]
);
```

but in case `prop.onChange` returns a function for whatever reason(that is rather unexpected but anyway) it will be used by `useEffect` as cleanup callback. So I've updated code to ensure we don't get unexpected call anyway

Comment: Function returned from `useEffect` will be run on unmount.

Comment: @Clarity, no, actually it works different way: 1) while you have some dependencies listed in `[]` function that is returned from `useCallback` will be run each time those dependencies are changes(right before they are changed)

Comment: 2) in code above it would happen only if `this.props.onChange(...)` returns a function as a result that is rather untypical. anyway, thank you for noticing, I've updated code to address that case anyway

Comment: My comment was about `useEffect(() => this.props.onChange(hDate), [..])` vs `useEffect(() => {
  this.props.onChange(hDate);}, [..])`, which do two different things.

Comment: I understand and added comment but I still stand on my own; `useEffect(() => this.props.onChange(...), [..])` calls `props.onChange`on dependencies ' changes and use _result_ as cleanup function(that runs _before_ dependencies are updated and last time on component unmount). But it rather unexpected `props.onChage(...)` to return a function

Comment: what you describe could happen if it was `useEffect(() => this.props.onChange, [])` without actual call, but it's not the case here

Comment: Well, that's what I was talking about and why your initial solution didn't work.

Comment: I've created small sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-glade-tfwdq What exact does not work?